# Server sending 400 on valid request from client

Tags: python, http, wireshark

I am using a third-party remote agent that sends a POST request on some event. The POST request can be sent to any server that accepts POST so I spun up a quick flask instance.

```py
# main.py

from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    # Logging request data to console
  return request.get_data()
```

This simple server works well and tested with Postman. Now, when the event occurs and the remote agent tries to send data to my server, I am getting below in the logs.

```
* Detected change in '/Users/my/path/main.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 000-000-000
192.168.1.2 - - [06/Aug/2020 12:06:39] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('POST')
192.168.1.2 - - [06/Aug/2020 12:06:39] "POST HTTP/1.1" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
```

Here's what I captured on wireshark:

```
POST HTTP/1.1
Host:192.168.1.1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Content-length: 6937
Content-type: text/xml
Connection: Keep-Alive

AgentID=ABCD
DataPoint=111
MoreDataPoint=222
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>Error response</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Error response</h1>
        <p>Error code: 400</p>
        <p>Message: Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('POST').</p>
        <p>Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST - Bad request syntax or unsupported method.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not able to figure out why my server is rejecting the request with 400.

Comment: HTTP/0.9 ?  This seems outdated. Could be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**HTTP/0.9 – The one-line protocol**

The initial version of HTTP had no version number; it has been later called 0.9 to differentiate it from the later versions. HTTP/0.9 is extremely simple: requests consist of a single line and start with the only possible method GET followed by the path to the resource (not the URL as both the protocol, server, and port are unnecessary once connected to the server).

0.9 has no "POST" method, so they are only sending a "GET".

Comment: Thank you, so you think the agent is actually sending a `GET` over `HTTP/0.9` and my server should accept `GET` and not `POST`? If so, why does the first line in the wireshark capture say `POST HTTP/1.1`?

Comment: That line is what the error page is using to send you the error, not what was sent to your server.  The agent needs to use http 1.1 or you need to accept GET requests.